# how do I find out the speed at which an equation changes it's direction to come up with an appropriate interval for my Bisection method

Tags: numerical-methods, matlab, bisection

I want to use bisection method to find all roots of an equation within a given domain. my algorithm logic is very simple , divide the given domain into sub domains such that for any given sub-domain only one root exists at most. check if f(a)*f(b)<0 if no then skip to next interval else find root(bisection). my problem however how do I decide the appropriate sub domain size? for a stable function that doesn't change direction often having a small interval would be a waste of time wheres for a fast "unstable" function using a big interval might risk having more than one root in an interval.

is there anyway that using the first two derivatives that I can tell me about the behavior of a function to come up with an appropriate interval accordingly?

Comment: You are assuming that a function with a root necessarily crosses (jumps from strictly positive to strictly negative values as $x$ goes from below the root to above), which is not in general true. For example, $f(x) = x^2$ (a smooth function) has a root at $x=0$, but there is no $a$, $b$, for which $f(a)*f(b) < 0$.

Comment: I didn't think of that, so far I've been using the intermediate value theorem as a criteria for my bisection algorithm, I don't want to change subject but I'm interested to know how to detected such roots?

Comment: A root of this form is a root of $f(x)$ and also of $f'(x)$ (since the root would then be a local extrema, provided it is only a double root; a triple root need not be an extrema, as $f(x) = x^3$ shows, but the root is still a root of both $f(x)$ and $f'(x)$). That said, I'll think about the original question a bit more.

Comment: that's interesting, for f(x)= x^2 the root at 0 can be detected using f′(a)*f′(b)<0 since it changes signs at first derivative, I'm still confused though on what criteria to use to detect such roots, do I use it in combination with IVT  or perhaps there's a different method of finding such root?

Comment: The trouble with me trying to give you a method for finding this root is that using the IVT would require you to either know what degree root it is (which defeats the purpose of your algorithm), or testing by brute force to figure out if there is an $n\in\mathbb{N}$ so that $f(a)*f^{(n)}(b) < 0$, but this is obviously not feasible, since $\mathbb{N}$ is infinite, so you would have to cut off at some large integer, but you might miss a root that has degree higher than that integer.

Comment: Another quick thing that comes to mind is that finding roots shouldn't need to depend on the IVT at all (assuming $f$ continuous). Maybe you could try testing a threshold for $|f(x)|$ instead. Surely, if there's a root at $c\in (a,b)$, then there is some subinterval of $(a,b)$ where $|f(x)| < \varepsilon$ for some very small $\varepsilon$. You could then narrow your search down to a subinterval where a certain threshold is met, and then try iterating that?